# Why does not jQuery.live function work with static elements?

Tags: html, dynamic, jquery

I have a dynamic HTML table, where I can add and remove rows.
Each row contains a button that has a class `removeRow`.

In my JavaScript, I have:

```
$('button.removeRow').live("click", function () {  
        var row = $(this).parents('tr')  
        row.remove();  
        return false;  
});
```

The problem is that it works for all buttons that belong to rows that were inserted after the page was loaded (by clicking on 'Add row' button).

It works for existing buttons, only if I change the above code to (but then it does not work for dynamically added rows):

```
$('button.removeRow').click(function () {  
        var row = $(this).parents('tr')  
        row.remove();  
        return false;  
});
```

I think that the live function should work for both, so can you point me into the right direction? Where can it go wrong?

Comment: live should work for existing rows, are you certain the button has the class removeRow?   what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a bug today. Somewhere in my code I had:

```
$('input[type=submit], button').click(function () {
            return false;
});
```

I wanted it to work with the submit button, so it would not submit the form on click. I do not remember why I put button there. Anyways, because of that my static button clicks were attached this event, while dynamically created ones were not. Therefore live 'click' worked for dynamic buttons. Stupid mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution: Do both

```
$('button.removeRow').live("click", function () {  
        var row = $(this).parents('tr')  
        row.remove();  
        return false;  
});
```

and

```
$('button.removeRow').click(function () {  
        var row = $(this).parents('tr')  
        row.remove();  
        return false;  
});
```

It would be helpful if you posted some example HTML as well as the code responsible for inserting new rows, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is going wrong if other tr elements are matched by your `.parents()` selector. Try `.closest()`:

```
$('button.removeRow').live("click", function(){  
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: No. The event is not executed at all, so it does not matter what is inside (I checked with firebug). I know that live should work, I will try to make an example tomorrow. I tried with two different versions of jQuery, no luck...

Answer (score 0):

The live should work for both dynamic and pre-rendered elements.

I'd start by working out if that content really exists before that jQuery is run...Try outputting the result of the following somewhere, or use the `debugger` keyword, or even the dreaded `alert`:

```
$('button.removeRow').length
// The rest of your click handler definition...
```